# .NET best coding practice to achieve compiler best performance?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Most of the time during coding, i found that whether i can write code in less number of line.

I don't know when we write some login in less number of line in c# then whether we achive good performance or not? whether dotnet compiler compile code faster or not?

Is there any source of tutorial/ book/ guideline so that we will make checklist before writing code.

Comment: Are you specifically asking about the time taken to compile the code? Or are you interested in the runtime performance of the compiled code?

Comment: @Mark: good point, I've answered from the point of view of performance of compiled code, but on re-reading it's possible he could be asking about compiler speed.

Comment: If you want it to compile faster, a: buy a faster CPU, b: buy a SSD

Comment: @Marc: lol +1,but u forgot to add "if its for work, don't ask your boss to buy them, just learn to accept what you have :)"

Comment: And also, don't write more than 1 method

Comment: What doest it means; more than one methd. means i don't write more than one method for one programm? Isn't

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What we should consider is writing better codes that other people can understand, declaring better variable names, maintain structure and design.

Of course we can write a login in 3 lines of code. Does that means compiler can compile/run it faster? Well, we should keep in mind that now-a-days compilers are extremely smart. Writing small number of lines of code doesn't prove that we're smart. And it also doesn't make sense compiler will compile faster.

Compilers optimizes our code to bytecodes very well and hence we should consider writing code considering designs and principles and of course human can understand the code as self code documented.

Here I quote what *Martin Fowler* said:

> Any fool can write code that a
>   computer can understand.  Good
>   programmers write code that humans can
>   understand.

Hope this helps!

With Regards,
Munim

Comment: Thanks Munim,

I will understand your point of view. Absolutly right. Is there any refrence for design and principle, guidelines recomende for asp.net

Answer (score 4):

To be honest, I think most people would prefer readable and maintainable code over code that compiles half a second faster.

If you're getting into the situation where your solution is taking minutes to compile, then you're clearly dealing with a lot of code, and the readability of it becomes all the more important.

**Edit to add**

Following on from some comments to the OP, work might well buy you faster CPUs and SSDs if you follow [XKCD's advice:](http://xkcd.com/303/)

[image: 'Are you stealing those LCDs?' 'Yeah, but I'm doing it while my code compiles.']

Answer (score 4):

No, writing code in less lines in a high level language like C# will almost never have any significnant impact on performance. Compilers are designed to optimise these things anyway.

The key to coding for best performance is make the code maintainable and natural first. More often than not this will be optimised by your compiler into well performing code, because the compiler has been designed to recognize these normal structures and optimise them the best way it can.

Avoid heavily nested loops where possible. Don't do work multiple times in a loop when it can be done once before the loop starts. Avoid making multiple database or network calls when 1 will do the job.

Performance test your code when it is finished and look for a bottleneck. Then spend time reviewing this bottleneck to see if you can optimise it. This will give you the best performance improvement for your time. Don't waste time early on in the project trying to optimise little things until you know they have a big effect on performance.

Your biggest performance hits are likely to be file access, database access, web service access. Operational stuff you just do in code is not likely to have a huge performance hit.

Comment: NB. There are certain things in .NET that should not be moved out of a loop (e.g. array length checks) --- the runtime special cases this to avoid all checks in the loop if you have the check in the control expression. If you move the length check out of the loop control expression, all the array accesses in the loop with be check: overall slower.

Comment: You one of my colleague always believe that instead of passing Form Object from Presentation layer to buiseness layer he prefer of passing variables as a argument by refrence. And according to him argument passing as arefrence is faster compare to passing Object.

Answer (score 2):

"less number of line"? This is not so relevant. Computing n'th Fibonacci number can be implemented recursively with exponential complexity or by using matrix multiplication in logarithmic time, with more lines of code. [Kolmogorov complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity) is not always to be minimized.

Look a rule: avoid unnecessary boxing, as in:

```
int x=3; Console.WriteLine("x ={0}", x); //wrong; but: Console.WriteLine("x ={0}", x.ToString());
```

I always regarded the book [Effective C#: 50 Specific Ways to Improve Your C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321245660) as a good book showing you how to write better code in C#; for example, it explains why you should use foreach instead of for when iterating over a collection.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking whether less lines of code is faster to compile than compiling more lines of code, the answer is, it depends.

You could potentially have 300 lines that compile far quicker than 50 lines.

Answer (score 1):

You asked for a book or article. One of the best books for best practices in .NET is

- [Framework Design Guidelines: Conventions, Idioms, and Patterns for Reusable .NET](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321246756)

The book is written by members of the .NET development team themselves.

Comment: I've read this book, and personally, although it is a good book, it also hasn't been updated since .net 2. I think a fair bit of stuff has changed, and it obviously doesn't cover any of the newer language features. You might find that reviewing the stylecop/fxcop rules will give you a more of an idea of current best practises.

Comment: The one I have is edition two which is aimed at .NET 3.5, but fxcop is a good alternative

Answer (score 0):

please see this book reference "Improving .NET Application Performance and Scalability": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649152.aspx

This is very good tutorial which covers most part of .NET application

Answer (score 0):

While not ASP.NET specific, I can highly recommend this free C#/VB.NET coding guidelines reference by Steven Sartain at SubMain. I don't think it will cover anything about how to write code that will compile fast, but I am not entirely sure why that would be anywhere near the top of you list of concerns. Just worry about writing good code.

http://submain.com/products/guidelines.aspx